# VirtualBox adapter MTU settings over 1500

Tags: virtual-machines, mtu

I create an adapter for Oracle VirtualBox (as a host-only). It runs perfectly; but I need to change MTU size to 1600. When I come back to host-PC and I opened terminal. Then I got these results.
ifconfig :
.....

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9618 (9.6 KB)
```

......

When I try to change MTU:

```
$ sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 mtu 1600
SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
```

There must be a way to change this interface's MTU; because it is not a real hardware. I also do same things for VMware; but same thing happened.

Comment: Why do you need to change the MTU to 1600 in the first place?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip -details link show vboxnet0` to your question.